# How to force MySQL to return empty row when condition does not matches?

Tags: mysql

I have a table tbl_transactions where I insert rows for the transaction made on different months, I want to get the sum of 'amount' every month. I can get this by GROUP BY 'month' column. Problem is that GROUP BY only returns rows for that month available on the tbl_transaction, Suppose month '09' has no data in my tbl_transaction I want to return the sum of all 01-12 months data with an empty row when any month is not available in my tbl_transaction
My tbl_transaction:
[image: My tbl_transaction]

My SQL:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as amount,month FROM tbl_transactions where type='2' AND year='2020' AND active='1' GROUP by month
```

Currently I am getting this, here the '09' month is missing as it has no data in the tbl_transaction. I want to return an empty row having 0 or null for the '09' month :
[image: Currently I am getting this, here the '09' month is missing as it has no data in the tbl_transaction. I want to return an empty row having 0 or null for the '09' month]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to display months, regardless of their occurance, you should build a reference table with all month names/references as required and left join it to your data table.

```
create table months
(
    month_id tinyint null,
    month_name varchar(25) null
);
```

Then insert your 12 static months as appropriate.

Then, you can use COALESCE for the `amount` value such as

```
SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(tt.amount), 0) as amount, mm.month_name as `month` FROM 
months mm 
LEFT JOIN tbl_transactions tt ON tt.month = mm.month_id AND tt.type='2' AND tt.year='2020' AND tt.active='1'
GROUP by mm.month_id
```

so that if amount is NULL it will be output as 0. Because it's a `LEFT JOIN` it will always output each month regardless of if it appears in the other (tbl_transactions) table.

Note that the conditionals of the SQL are moved from `WHERE` to `ON` so you do not have an active WHERE clause in this SQL.

Comment: No bro, I am not getting zero for the month '09' rather this is missing from the result as my previous query. You can check the new query

SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(tt.amount), 0) as amount, mm.month_name as month FROM 
tbl_months mm 
LEFT JOIN tbl_transactions tt ON tt.month = mm.month_num
WHERE tt.type='2' AND tt.year='2020' AND tt.active='1' GROUP by tt.month  
@Martin

Comment: @ArifMuhammad please note that you need to move the criteria from the `WHERE` clause and put it in the `ON` clause. Please refresh your view of my answer and try again.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks @Martin